# How to redirect different languages with express for Google

Tags: node.js, express, http, seo, multilingual

I am running a web app on two languages. This is working fine but Google does not index my language directories. Google just shows domain.com in stead of domain.com/en/ or domain.com/de/.

I am working with 301 redirects using express js but I am not sure why Google is not indexing it.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const language = req.acceptsLanguages()[0].slice(0, 2).toLowerCase();
    if (language === 'de') {
        res.redirect(301, '/de/');
    } else if (language === 'en') {
        res.redirect(301, '/en/');
    } else {
        res.redirect(301, '/en/');
    }
});

// provide german
app.get('/de/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/de/index.html'));
});

// provide english
app.get('/en/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/en/index.html'));
});
```

So the redirecting ist working fine but the indexing fails. How do I have to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

The Google crawler will only access pages that are available through links. The various language pages are hidden to the crawler by the app logic.

However I would recommend that you use an existing internationalization module for NodeJS, such as i18n: https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n.

Comment: Would it help, if I redirect not on the app layer but on the proxy layer? I am using some kind of load balancer where I can put in rules.

Comment: No server-side redirects would help with the Google indexing.